# How to use ember-pusher in ember-cli project

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, pusher

pusher in ember-cli project. I am sorry but i find if difficult to get my head around js tools.

[Ember pusher github](https://github.com/jamiebikies/ember-pusher)

steps done so for.

1. Inside ember-cli project: bower install --save pusher
2. In broccoli.js file added line: app.import('vendor/pusher/dist/pusher.js');
   in .jshintrc

`"predef": {
        "document": true,
        "window": true,
        "MyappENV": true,
        "Pusher": true
    }`

1. Then copied ember-pusher.amd.js from [git mentioned link](https://ember-pusher-builds.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-pusher.amd.js) and saved in /vendor folder.
2. In broccoli.js file added line:

   `var App = Ember.Application.extend({
      modulePrefix: 'Myapp', // TODO: loaded via config
      Resolver: Resolver,
      PUSHER_OPTS: {
          key: '586f8kjhfkdf8d7f9',
          connection: {},
          logAllEvents: true
      },
   });`

5.In app.js.

`var App = Ember.Application.extend({
         modulePrefix: 'Myapp',
         Resolver: Resolver,
         PUSHER_OPTS: {
             key: '586f8kjhfkdf8d7f9',
             connection: {},
             logAllEvents: true
        }
    });`

6. In application.js controller

```
 import Ember from 'ember';
  export
  default Ember.Controller.extend({
      PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS: {
          myChannel: ['my-event']
      },
      actions: {
          myEvent: function () {
              console.log('Event my event was triggered xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
          }
      }
  });
```

I donot get any error message but pusher dashboard does not show any connections

```
   app.import('vendor/ember-pusher/ember-pusher.amd.js', {
     exports: {
         'ember-pusher': [
             'controller',
             'binding',
             'clientevents',
             'initialize'
         ]
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

There is now an ember addon for this, with instructions in the README: https://github.com/ivanvotti/ember-cli-pusher

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to get it working:

1. bower install --save pusher
2. Download `ember-pusher.js` to `vendor/ember-pusher/ember-pusher.js` from https://github.com/jamiebikies/ember-pusher#download
3. Add the following to your Brocfile.js

   `app.import('bower_components/pusher/dist/pusher.js');`
   `app.import('vendor/ember-pusher/ember-pusher.js');`
4. Add the following to `config/environment.js`

   `ENV.APP.PUSHER_OPTS = { key: 'your-app-key', connection: {     } }`
5. Log events from one of your controllers

   `import Ember from 'ember';
    export default Ember.Controller.extend(EmberPusher.Bindings, {
     logPusherEvents: true,
     PUSHER_SUBSCRIPTIONS: {
       myChannel: ['my-event']
     }
   }`